# Why is UIViewRepresentable's makeUIView and updateUIView got called so many time xcode Playground?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift-playground, uiviewrepresentable

I have a simple SwiftUI wrap with UIKit as display on Playground (using Xcode 12.1)

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        WrapView()
    }
}

struct WrapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        print("makeUIView")
        return UIView(frame: .infinite)
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        print("updateUIView")
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

I'm surprised to see so many calls to `makeUIView` and `updateUIView` as shown below

```
makeUIView
updateUIView
makeUIView
updateUIView
makeUIView
updateUIView
makeUIView
updateUIView
updateUIView
updateUIView
updateUIView
updateUIView
```

Comment: It is specific to PlaygroundPage, and, actually, you should not care about that - just do what is required in each method.